# ODE: Initial Value Problem with a Change of Variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

this is a question that's had me sort of stumped. Any points or help would be greatly appreciated, I've never been that great at differential equations

[The question at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idL97.png)

The presence of the alpha seems to throw off any actual working I do such as manipulating for a value of y prime, and I'd rather use an integration factor but the change of variables has been specified for? I also can't seem to find any change of variable questions similar enough to follow the working. Thanks in advance to whoever helps out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'-2xy=\dfrac {x^3}{y^3}$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation.
$$y^3y'-2xy^4=x^3$$
Note that $(y^4)'=4y^3y'$. Substitute $v=y^4$ and solve.

You can surely take it from here.

Comment: Ah! Completely missed that by just trying to take it head on, but that makes so much sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. The differential equation is now linear of first order. Thats easy to solve. Also take a look at the wiki page on the Bernoulli differential equation. @AlexStephens